# How to arrive to / calculate gravitational acceleration on Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, earth

What are the exact steps and figures to calculate gravitational acceleration on Earth (*9.8 m/s^2*) and where do these figures come from?

*(Please use an algebraic explanation, but assume understanding of the principles of calculus without being handy with the notation.)*

I'm assuming (getting some figures from WolframAlpha) we're looking at something along the lines of these for values:

> *G = [6.674×10^-11](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=value%20of%20gravitational%20constant) [image: m^3 kg^-1 s^-2]*
>
> *m(earth) = [5.9721986×10^24 kg](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what%20is%20the%20mass%20of%20earth)*
>
> *d(r of earth) = [6371.0088 km](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what%20is%20the%20radius%20of%20earth)*

As far as the simplest answer, I'd be happy with some pointers to solid reference material in addition to a simple walkthrough of the equation.

Comment: Are you taking those values as given? Then just use Newton's Law of Gravitation and his second Law. GMm/r^2=mg, and cancel the arbitrary m's.

Comment: HUGH MUNGUS WHAT?! :D So yeah, I actually did that but the units, for some peculiar reason, aren't working out just right. Eg, I get 9,819,831...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Newtonian perspective, every particle of mass ($m_j$) produces a gravitational field in the space surrounding it:
$$\vec{g}_j=\dfrac{-Gm_j}{r^2}\hat{r},$$
where $r$ is the distance from the mass to the point in space you're interested in, and $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector pointing from the mass toward the point in space.

If you have several masses, the gravitational field at a point is the sum of all the individual fields from the individual masses. If you place a separate mass, $M$, at that point in space, it will experience a force:
$$\vec{F}_{\mathrm{on }M}=M \sum_j \vec{g}_j=M\vec{g}_{\mathrm{net}}.$$
As a consequence of applying Newton's 2nd Law to this force, we find that the acceleration is equal to the gravitational field:$$\vec{a}=\vec{g}_{\mathrm{net}}.$$

For spherically symmetric mass distributions it turns out [(see Gauss's law for gravity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law_for_gravity) that the net gravitational field (that sum) is equal to the field of a single, large mass as the same location as the center of the distribution. In other words, for a planet or a star, the gravitational field at a distance $r$ from the center of that object is simply
$$\vec{g}=\dfrac{-Gm_{\mathrm{total}}}{r^2}\hat{r}.$$
This holds for any distance $r$ larger than the radius of the sphere, so not only can you use it to find the gravitational field at the surface of Earth, but also 2000 km above the surface (where it will be less).

Comment: Okay, thanks for that and you both confirmed a couple of things and expanded my sight as well. Now on a practical level, effectively you have (6.674×10^-11) × (5.9721986×10^24/6371.0088^2). In this my units are not simplifying out properly with it being several orders of magnitude off.  Can you clarify, in a practical sense, what values to use there with the appropriate output?

Comment: G = 6.674×10^-11 m^3 kg^-1 s^-2

    m(earth) = 5.9721986×10^24 kg

    d(r of earth) = 6371.0088 km, You need to change the d to meters to make sure all the parameters have the same units for length. i.e 6371.0088 km = 6371008.8 m. Use this in your calculating and you'll get the right answer.

Comment: So, considering this, could one ascertain the mass of an option (person, etc.)  by simply reversing the formula and solving for `m` in the following equation: [W(e) = m * g(e)](https://cl.ly/2w1y322f381k/weight_equation.png)

Comment: Yes, we have refined values for masses of the Earth and for other planets and  moons by measuring the orbits of satellites and probes around and past them.

Comment: Super, yes, the goal here has been to actually play with `G` as per some fascinating studies I've seen to test a hypothesis at some varied locations. It is rather easy to corroborate this by use of precise `weight` results. Just wanted to firm some things up first and you've done a fine job at explaining the above.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way is the use the Universal Gravitation Law, where M1 = mass of Earth and M2 = mass of object being accelerated by the earth.

F = (G)(M1)(M2) / r^2

Here we divide M2 by both sides:

F / M2 = (G)(M1) / r^2

Since we know F = Ma, F / M2 = a, which is the acceleration due to gravity by Earth:

a = (G)(M1) / r^2

Now you simply plug in your values for G, M1, and r.

G is the universal gravitation constant, which is just a number that was derived to solve gravitational attraction problems.

r is the distance from both masses' centres.  If your object was falling at the surface of the earth, r = Earth's radius (which is the distance from Earth's surface to the centre).  If your object was, let's say, 5000 km above the surface of Earth, r = 5000 km + radius of Earth.

Hope that helps.